# neo4j embedded in android app wont build

Tags: neo4j

I am getting this error when I follow instructions on this page:
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mobile-android

When I use ant clean debug, this is the error I get :

```
/Downloads/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/Documents/neo4j/neo4j-android/build.xml:758: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/Documents/neo4j/neo4j-android/build.xml:782: targetApi attribute value must be an integer



Line 782 in neo4j build.xml : thepreviousBuildType="${build.last.is.packaging.debug}"
Line 758 in neo4j build.xml : elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping aidl/renderscript/R.java"
Line 601 in android ant build.xml : antfile="build.xml"
```

The target api is properly set in android manifest file and the sdk itself is installed correctly.

I need to use the embedded neo4j graph database in my android app, I cannot make server calls since the app has to be offline.